# Disturbing grey boxes in google maps view

Tags: android, google-maps-api-2

[image]

As you can see in the picuture there are little grey boxes in my map view. Has anybody a hint what is causing them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have used `mapView.setStreetView(true);` remove this line and check again. And also reduce zoom if you have zoomed too much.

Comment: I was just playing with Maps and had the exact same issue on my device. removing setStreetView solved the problem for me.

Comment: hello! well this is the answer! Now I have neither set setStreetView(true) nor setSatelliteView(true) and it works!! Do you know the purpose for this?

Comment: I can't tell if it is a bug or a feature :D